# How to append input type hidden or text into a cell you know exactly position by jquery

Tags: jquery

I got stuck with my form

How to append input type hidden or text into a cell you know exactly position by jquery

Example i have 4 rows 3 cells

i want to append input type hidden or text into rows 3 cells 2

how can i do it?

Thank to your answer or suggestion

Comment: Post your html and javascript code too plz, else it's hard to say.

Comment: Use something like http://jsfiddle.net/ to post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one http://jsfiddle.net/yoku2010/VLwwP/

```
​$(document.createElement("input")).attr("type","text").appendTo($("table tr:eq(2) td:eq(1)"));​​
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var inputHidden = $('#yourinput');
$('table tr:eq(2) td:eq(1)').append(inputHidden);
```

The selector :eq receive the index of element that you want to select as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery append http://jsfiddle.net/RAf9k/

```
$('table tr:eq(2) td:eq(1)').append('text');​
```